# how to remove lodash from this line

Tags: javascript, lodash

I need to remove lodash from an old project I never used lodash before so I couldn't understand and couldn't find an example for this one.
how to change this :
`_.find(x, ['y', z])`
is that equal to:

```
x.find( (e) => (e.y === y && e.z === z))
```

Comment: You'll need to show us the data structures, and a bit more of your code. But if it's just a flad data structure, then it would be: `x.find((y) => x === y)` (but if you wouldn't need to use .find for something so simlpe)

Comment: Actually it's just `x.find(e => e.y === z);` It's the *' \`_.matchesProperty\` iteratee shorthand.'*, see: [_.find](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#find)

Comment: The OP is close, it should be `e.y == z`

Comment: it doesn't use strict equality? I have no idea.